# simple-notifications options don't set

Tags: angular, typescript

I have added `simple-notifications` plugin to my project. When I call notification, it appears but with default options. My options don't set.

**app.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [ ItemsService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {

  public options = {
    position: ["bottom", "right"],
    timeOut: 3000,
    lastOnBottom: true,
    maxStack: 3,
    animate: "fromBottom"
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
<simple-notifications [options]="options"></simple-notifications>    
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

When I call notification, it appears but without my options. Why options don't set, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your options when you are importing the module to your app module like this,

```
imports: [
// your other modules
SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot({
    ...options
})
]
```